# Google Apps Script ToggleButton usage

Tags: google-apps-script

How to make use of google-apps-script's ToggleButton?

The [toggleButton doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/toggle-button)
explains how to get info such as mouse position or various modifier key status in its event handler, but I still can't figure out the very basic -- how to get the status of the ToggleButton, and use it.

Please help me complete the following sample, so that the ToggleButton will toggle between counting up or counting down (chars typed so far, or remaining # of chars allowed).

```
var max = 124;

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel(); 
  var text = app.createTextArea().setName("text");
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("count").addCallbackElement(panel);
  var toggleButton = app.createToggleButton('So far', 'Remaining').setId('btn');
  app.add(panel);
  panel.add(text);
  panel.add(toggleButton); //Add a UI Widget
  panel.add(app.createButton("Count", handler));
  panel.add(app.createLabel("0 characters").setId("label"));
  return app;
}

function count(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  // Because the text area was named "text" and added as a callback element to the
  // button's click event, we have its value available in eventInfo.parameter.text.
  var text;
  if (e.parameter.btn == true) {
    text = "counting up";
  } else {
    text = "counting down";
  }
  app.getElementById("label").setText(e.parameter.text.length + " characters, " + text);
  return app;
}
```

Thanks Serge for your answer. I'm still struggling with the making use of it part, as I am really learn by example now. I've changed my code to yours, adding the effort of trying to make use of it. However, I can see that text length change each time I click on the Count Button, but the result of the toggleButton is not toggling.

Thanks

Comment: As I said , the returned value is a string ...so you  have to add quotes to "true" :-)

Comment: Note also that you could use a keyUpHandler on your textBox instead of a count button and get rid of the count button to simplify your layout and make the UI easier to use...(this is only a suggestion)

Comment: "the result is a stringified boolean", I thought that was the result of `Logger.log` from the context... In fact that was already my second guess, my first one was `if (e.parameter.btn) {`. Sorry for being dense. Thanks a lot for your help. FTR, I do need a Button for my real case. This is only a simplified case. Thanks again.

Comment: As I said: "only a suggestion" :-) thanks and good luck...(sorry for this ambiguous answer, I'll edit to make it -hopefully- more clear)

Comment: thank you for your meticulous and persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough you can get the value using its `ID` (normally we have to use the widgets `Name` as you said)

I modified a bit your code by adding a `panel` to hold all the widgets so I have a single `callbackElement` to assign to the handler.
I show the toggle button result in a `Logger.log` because I don't know the final purpose and didn't feel like imagining a code for nothing ;-)

**Note :** the value returned by `e.parameter.btn` is a string representation of a boolean value : "true" or "false" as usual for widgets having a logic state...

[test code here with result shown](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxjE4Y0R9qiTtA6mOfqDEWwBc6N-VCLB4H9cZzkTUZABkhNqC8/exec)

```
var max = 124;

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel(); 
  var text = app.createTextArea().setName("text");
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("count").addCallbackElement(panel);
  var toggleButton = app.createToggleButton('So far', 'Remaining').setId('btn');
  app.add(panel);
  panel.add(text);
  panel.add(toggleButton); //Add a UI Widget
  panel.add(app.createButton("Count", handler));
  panel.add(app.createLabel("0 characters").setId("label"));
  return app;
}

function count(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  // Because the text area was named "text" and added as a callback element to the
  // button's click event, we have its value available in eventInfo.parameter.text.
  app.getElementById("label").setText(e.parameter.text.length + " characters");
  Logger.log(e.parameter.btn);
  return app;
}
```

---

**EDIT :** here is your code modified to work as you want (note the "" on the e.parameter.btn value and the new handler trigger) - demo code updated.

```
var max = 124;

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel(); 
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("count").addCallbackElement(panel);
  var text = app.createTextArea().setName("text").setPixelSize(180,100).addKeyUpHandler(handler);
  var toggleButton = app.createToggleButton('So far', 'Remaining').setId('btn');
  app.add(panel);
  panel.add(text);
  panel.add(toggleButton); //Add a UI Widget
  panel.add(app.createLabel("0 characters").setId("label"));
  return app;
}

function count(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var toggle = e.parameter.btn == "false";// this way I convert the string value in a "real" boolean
  if(toggle){
    app.getElementById("label").setText(e.parameter.text.length + " characters  (toggle btn = "+e.parameter.btn+')');
  }else{
    app.getElementById("label").setText(max-Number(e.parameter.text.length) + " characters  (toggle btn = "+e.parameter.btn+')');
  }  return app;
}
```